# How to split single column comma separated values into multiple column and left joint to each cell from another table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I need a solution to create view in MySQL.
I have two table of data. One have list of customer names.

```
Table: name_list
Id          Name
------------------
12345       Steve
23456       Mick
34567       Robert
45678       John
56789       Taylor
67890       Steven
23234       Ken
56746       Harry
```

another have customer groups.

```
Table: customer_group
Group       Customers
----------------------
A5213       12345,34567,56789
B5314       23234
D5486       23456,45678,67890,56746
```

Now I need to show these data by splitting comma separated customer id from customer_group table and join name of those customers from name_list table.

```
View: customer_name_result
Group   Cust1   Name1   Cust2   Name2   Cust3   Name3   Cust4   Name4
----------------------------------------------------------------------
A5213   12345   Steve   34567   Robert  56789   Taylor  NULL    NULL
B5314   23234   Ken     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
D5486   23456   Mick    45678   John    67890   Steven  56746   Harry
```

Comment: You should rewrite logic of  keeping data more relational. Or develop php script that will fetch and generate new table with necessary data (:

Comment: See normalisation

Comment: is there a way to do it in MySQL to create view. @num8er

Comment: @RafayetUllah unfortunately not, cuz Your requirement has main problem: `dynamic count of columns in result` what if there are 100 user ids in one group? Also splitting strings, looping and etc operations using stored procedures and etc is very cost based thing. I recommend You to have table: `customer_group` with repeating `Group` and `Customer` (single id) columns - in this case You can easily do join and etc. But very easy (cheapes) way without changing structure is to write php script and generate `.csv` file if it should be report to be sent by mail. Otherwise do data normalization.

Comment: @num8er is there a way if one group have max 8-10 customer?

Comment: @RafayetUllah where this resulting table will be used? In web interface? Or just once a month to give reports?

Comment: @num8er it will be used in web interface and I am already using php script to get this job done. But I am trying to do the same thing in MySQL server so that I can use this view to other MySQL views.

Comment: @RafayetUllah believe me with Your current structure it will be slow for mysql and it may lock tables in critical times. You can make script and put it to cron that will generate table for Your needs in database every minute. (:

Comment: Also view is just simple sql query that's called everytime when You select view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot as below:

```
;with cte as (
    select [Group], [Value], nl.[name], RowN = Row_Number() over(partition by [Group] order by [Value]) 
        ,RowN1 = Row_Number() over(partition by [Group] order by [Value]) +1000
        from customer_group cg
    cross apply
    (
        Select * from string_split(customers,',')
    ) a
    inner join name_list nl
    on a.value = nl.id
)  
select [Group],   max([1001]) as [Name1], max([1]) as [Val1] 
                , max([1002]) as [Name2], max([2]) as [Val1]
                , max([1003]) as [Name3], max([3]) as [Val1]
                , max([1004]) as [Name4], max([4]) as [Val1]
from
(select * from cte ) b  
pivot (max([value]) for RowN in([1],[2],[3],[4])) p
pivot (max([name]) for RowN1 in ([1001],[1002],[1003],[1004])) p1
group by [Group]
```

Answer as below:

```
+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
| Group | Name1  | Val1  | Name2  | Val1  | Name3  | Val1  | Name4  | Val1  |
+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
| A5213 | Steve  | 12345 | Robert | 34567 | Taylor | 56789 | NULL   | NULL  |
| B5314 | Ken    | 23234 | NULL   | NULL  | NULL   | NULL  | NULL   | NULL  |
| D5486 | Mick   | 23456 | John   | 45678 | Harry  | 56746 | Steven | 67890 |
+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
```